# Login problem after Ubuntu update to 16.04 version

Tags: login

I just updated Ubuntu to 16.04 version on my PC and now I'm not able to reach the desktop because a black window appears and ask for login + password. There's only on session and I was used to enter the password, but not the login. I tried to enter login and password several times, but I never succeeded to log on.
I tried to find a convenient solution on different forums, but I'm always stuck in front of the same window.
I have to say that I'm a real beginner.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's going on with the black screen, but you can reset your password in Ubuntu. Googling for "ubuntu reset password" gives several explanations.

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Hi SPRBRN, thank you for your help. I'm sure about my password. I was not used to enter a login, and now Ubuntu ask for it, that's my problem, ...

Comment: See the link. Enter Grub, then choose to open the terminal. There you can look up the usernames: `ls -al /home/` will probably give it away, otherwise `cat /etc/passwd`.

Comment: You may have selected a wrong entry in grub once, and now that is selected for startup. Try all different options there and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried several times by choosing recovery mode, but it don't reach to the recovery menu, still the black window asking for login... I even tried the memory test (so long, and nothing changed).

Comment: You can try to use a Live CD or Stick. Then you can browse the contents of you disk and see your username. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/ Another option is Live Recovery. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery Anyway - make a backup of your data when you have the live-stick running. You can now access everything, so make that backup, maybe even a complete system backup, so if you decide to reinstall, you have all your data safe.

Comment: Ok, let me try this and I come back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Well, thanks to the bootable USB key, I succeeded to launch with Ubuntu 14.04. I try to access to my files (on a partition for data), but system says that I don't have the rights to do it. Do you know why ? I tried also the use a restoration point, but none seems to be available...

Comment: That's normal behavior, nothing to worry about. You don't have rights because the user which you used/created on the original system doesn't exist on the live system. You should use sudo to copy these files to an external backup disk. Don't change the rights on the original disk if you still want to repair that. On the backup disk you can use `chown` to change the owner.

Comment: Finally, I have found login for the first installation. So, I logged on in the black window. Then the message delivered show that the upgrade was stopped during the processus. I've seen some hints in others conversation in the forum and finally I succeeded to continue the upgrade. Now, I'm stuck with a problem with cgmanager and systemd-shim ("des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution ")...

Comment: OK, well I think that deserves another question. This question won't attract the attention you need. You can accept and/or upvote an answer if you feel that it helped you.

Comment: Finally, I started the system again and downloaded the missing files. So I recovered my account and all my files !!! Thank you very much for helping !

Answer (score 0):

I dont belive that the password is the issue. try pressing ctrl+alt+f1 to go to terminal mode and login from there. if you can login then i could be your lightdm that is having issuers. reinstall ligthdm. if you have special nvidia drivers installed, then reinstall them.

Comment: Hi Pierre. Thank you for your help. I can't reach the terminal, I try by pressing CTRL+alt+F1, but it never happen. By turning on my computer, I reach a page (GRUB ?) where I can choose Ubuntu, advanced options for Ubuntu and memory tests. After this, the black window asking for login appears..

Comment: Hi! the i would suggest that you try to ssh to the computer and login that way..